# CIDetector featuresInImage returning 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, core-image, cidetector

I'm trying to get the text area on a image using core detector.

```
- (NSArray *)detectWithImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    // prepare CIImage
    CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage];

    // flip vertically
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineTransform"];
    [filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, CGRectGetHeight(image.extent));
    t = CGAffineTransformScale(t, 1.0, -1.0);
    [filter setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:t] forKey:kCIInputTransformKey];
    image = filter.outputImage;


    // prepare CIDetector
    CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeText
                                              context:nil
                                              options:@{
                                                        CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];
    // retrive array of CITextFeature
    NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:image
                                          options:@{CIDetectorReturnSubFeatures: @YES}];

    return features;
}
```

The image passed is:

[image]

I get nothing from this image. I tried with color image as well and also without flipping the image.

Can someone point me in right direction ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should check to make sure the `UIImage` and `img.CGImage` being passed into your function are not `nil`, as the rest of your code seems to be fine, though the flip is not necessary. For example:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: img];
CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage];

CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeText
                                              context:nil
                                              options:@{
                                                        CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];
// retrive array of CITextFeature
NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:image options:@{CIDetectorReturnSubFeatures: @YES}];

for(CITextFeature *feature in features) {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(feature.bounds.origin.x, image.size.height - fear.bounds.origin.y - feature.bounds.height, fear.bounds.width, feature.bounds.height)];
    view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent: 0.25];
    [imageView addSubview: view];
}
```

Produced the result:
[image]

Where the red highlight represents the bounds returned from the `CIDetector`

Comment: Surprisingly this returns 0 when run on iOS 9 simulator. This returns proper values on iOS 11 simulator though. I'm wondering why it is like that, as the documentation says CIDetector is available since iOS 5+

Comment: `CIDetectorTypeText` was introduced in iOS 9 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cidetectortypetext but that is weird if it's not detecting in the simulator.